# OpenGL ES based graphing library for iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, objective-c++, graphing

I'm trying to graph large amounts of data, say around a million data points in a line graph. I've tried CorePlot, but it is somewhat lacking in speed. It couldn't even graph 30,000 points with any sort of usable rendering speed (less than 1 fps). s7graphview is somewhat similar to CorePlot but with less features. I put together a simple OpenGL ES project and graphed 1,000,000 points and it rendered at around 10 fps, which is a very usable speed for manipulating a graph. My question is this, are there any purely OpenGL ES based graphing libraries for the iPhone? If not, are there any open source OpenGL based ones I could potentially port to the iPhone? I'd rather not resort to writing my own graphing library unless absolutely necessary.

#### Edit:

Ok, since there aren't any takers, would anyone be willing to work together with me to make an Open Source OpenGL ES graphing library?

#### Update:

I've finished my OpenGL graphing library. It can graph 1,400,000 points at 10 fps with multiple lines and multiple scales attached to those lines, with dynamic resizing and it is a self contained control that can be dropped onto any window/view. Much better than CorePlot's 10,000 points at 10 fps.

Comment: Davido - I'm starting to run into the same thing. Are you planning on open sourcing your library?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll need to talk with management about it and see if they want to go that route or start selling it to developers, since there doesn't seem to be any other library out there that does this. I'll check.

Comment: That'd be great. Let me know either way, I can be reached on twitter @rexeisen.

Comment: Sorry, but they don't want any of our code we develop to be available outside of the company, paid or free. Hope you can find another solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Davido why would you need to graph 1,400,000 points at once when there are not that many pixels to see them? Wouldn't it make more sense to draw from a selection of samples and sample more  data as you zoom?